# Get-ADReplicationsite Filter-Values

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I found a script filtering Sites in the Active Directory:

```
Get-ADReplicationSite -Filter{WhenCreated -gt <date>}
```

I just wonder how do I know all the possible Filter-Values, in this case "WhenCreated"? I've tried:

```
help Get-ADReplication -full
help about_ActiveDirectory_ObjectModel
```

but found nothing?
Thanks for help.

Comment: They're not filter values, they're property values. Pipe it to a `Select-Object *`, or if the cmdlet has a `-property`, you can specify the asterisk `*` to it.

Comment: nope, there is no property "WhenCreated" when I start:
    Get-ADReplicationSite | select -property *
There is a property "PropertyNames" (an array) but:
    Get-ADReplicationSite | select -expandProperty PropertyNames 
has no property "WhenCreated" as well. So I think this must be a value of the -Filter.

Comment: What you're filtering by, is a property value. Glad you tried the built-in help system first, a lot of people disregard it.

Answer (score 0):

my fault:
`Get-ADReplicationSite -property * -filter * | select -property *`
reveals the property: WhenCreated.